# Python Breaking a While Loop with user input

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, user-input

new to Python. Within a while loop, I'm asking the user for an input which is a key for a dict. and then print the value of that key. This process should continue until the input does not match any key in the dict. I'm using an if statement to see if the key is in the dict. If not I'like the while loop to break. So far I can't get it to break.

Thank you all

```
Animal_list = {
    'lion': 'carnivora', 'bat': 'mammal', 'anaconda': 'reptile',
    'salmon': 'fish', 'whale': 'cetaceans', 'spider': 'arachnida',
    'grasshopper': 'insect', 'aligator': 'reptile', 'rat': 'rodents',
    'bear': 'mammal', 'frog': 'amphibian', 'turtles': 'testudines'
}
while True:
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if choice == choice:
        print "%s is a %s" % (choice, Animal_list[choice])
    elif choice != choice:
        break
```

Comment: I will also suggest same as @christopher has suggested, python has "in" operator, which is used to check membership in a sequence , strings, tuples etcetra. you can check for example in this link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`choice == choice` will always be true.  What you really want to do is check if `choice` is in the `Animal_list`. Try changing to this:

```
Animal_list = {
    'lion': 'carnivora', 'bat': 'mammal', 'anaconda': 'reptile',
    'salmon': 'fish', 'whale': 'cetaceans', 'spider': 'arachnida',
    'grasshopper': 'insect', 'aligator': 'reptile', 'rat': 'rodents',
    'bear': 'mammal', 'frog': 'amphibian', 'turtles': 'testudines'
}
while True:
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if choice in Animal_list:
        print "%s is a %s" % (choice, Animal_list[choice])
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. I'm always surprise how python is so close to english

Comment: My pleasure! If an answer here solves your problem, please mark it as accepted if you don't mind :)